# How can I prevent firefox from closing when I press ctrl-w

Tags: firefox

In my favorite editor (vim), I regularly use ctrl-w to execute a certain action. Now, it quite often happens to me that firefox is the active window (on windows) while I still look at vim (thinking vim is the active window) and press ctrl-w which closes firefox. This is not what I want. Is there a way to stop ctrl-w from closing firefox?

Rene

Comment: Happens to me too every now and then because in IntelliJ IDEA Ctrl-W means something else and gets used a lot...

Comment: Ctrl/Cmd+W is supposed to close the current window/tab on all OS. In fact this is an accesibility bug in IntelliJ products and it already have a bug opened at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73775?query=close+window+shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really found a solution to my problem, but the best thing I could come up with is to press `CTRL-SHIFT-T` which re-opens the last tab that was closed with `CTRL-W`.

Unfortunatelly, this may not bring back the text you were typing in a form.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox can be configured not to close the window when you close the last tab. Use `about config` to set `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`to `false`.

If you don't even want firefox to close *tabs* with C-t, then you'll have to use something like keyconfig to change the shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

[Keyconfig extension](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) <-- Could be what your looking for.  It lets you change the keyboard bindings in Firefox.

Comment: Can you garantee it's not malware or something like that? The webpage is obscure, points to a huge forum thread, doesn't say the licence and doen't show the source code. I only found the binary to install...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a universal greasemonkey script that embeds a Flash SWF into the page that intercepts keystrokes.

Then again, you're probably not looking for a programmatic solution. Try [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl-W = Close Tab. It closes the browser when no tabs are left. Open a new blank tab, and it shouldn't cause the whole browser to close (just that tab).

Comment: I assume that closing *any* tab is not appreciated by the question asker?

Comment: Opening a new tab will help there aswell. Unless he presses it twice.